# Is outgoing Azure traffic firewalled?

Tags: networking, azure, firewall

I have a Windows VM in Azure that I'm using for VS2015 experiments.

Google Drive is unable to contact update servers to finish its own installation (despite Chrome/Omaha working fine).

Apparently, I also can't clone git repos over ssh, even though HTTPS seems to be working.

Disabling the Windows Firewall does not seem to remedy these issues.

Suggestions?

Comment: These seems to have magically resolved itself, which isn't exactly confidence inspiring.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open endpoints on the vm.  HTTPs and HTTP are open.  If you need other ports...then you need to find them and open them as endpoints.  My guess is that's what is happening here.

Comment: "Is **outgoing** traffic firewalled". I'm aware of the firewall on incoming endpoints.